# MPAndroidChart stacked bar chart shows wrong/duplicated values

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart, dayofweek

I'm trying to build a bar chart to show daily data of the week using MPAndroidChart. the data is shown localized so they're arranged depending on the first day of the week (Monday or Sunday). Some data get duplicated and added to several bars and some are show in wrong bars. I've been trying to solve this for a week and had no luck.

This is how I process data:

```java
List<String> dailyIncomes = new ArrayList<>(7);
        List<String> dailyExpenses = new ArrayList<>(7);
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
            dailyIncomes.add("0");
            dailyExpenses.add("0");
        }
for (int i = 0; i < transactionsList.size(); i++) {
            TransactionItem currentTransaction = transactionsList.get(i);
            DateTimeHandler dateTimeHandler = new DateTimeHandler(currentTransaction.getUserDate()); //my own class to get day, week or year
            int transactionYear = dateTimeHandler.getYear();
            int transactionWeek = dateTimeHandler.getWeekOfYear();
            int transactionDay = dateTimeHandler.getDayOfWeek();
            if (transactionWeek == week && transactionYear == year) {
       for (int d = 0; d < 7; d++) {
                    if (d + 1 == transactionDay) {
                        if (weekFields.getFirstDayOfWeek().getValue() == 7) {
                            if (transactionDay == 7) {
                                if (currentTransaction.getPrefix().equals("+")) {
                                    double dailyTotal = Double.parseDouble(dailyIncomes.get(0)) + currentTransaction.getAmountValue();
                                    dailyIncomes.add(0, "" + dailyTotal);
                                } else {
                                    double dailyTotal = Double.parseDouble(dailyExpenses.get(0)) + currentTransaction.getAmountValue();
                                    dailyExpenses.add(0, "" + dailyTotal);
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (currentTransaction.getPrefix().equals("+")) {
                                    double dailyTotal = Double.parseDouble(dailyIncomes.get(d + 1)) + currentTransaction.getAmountValue();
                                    dailyIncomes.add(d + 1, "" + dailyTotal);
                                } else {
                                    double dailyTotal = Double.parseDouble(dailyExpenses.get(d + 1)) + currentTransaction.getAmountValue();
                                    dailyExpenses.add(d + 1, "" + dailyTotal);
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            if (currentTransaction.getPrefix().equals("+")) {
                                double dailyTotal = Double.parseDouble(dailyIncomes.get(d)) + currentTransaction.getAmountValue();
                                dailyIncomes.add(d, "" + dailyTotal);
                            } else {
                                double dailyTotal = Double.parseDouble(dailyExpenses.get(d)) + currentTransaction.getAmountValue();
                                dailyExpenses.add(d, "" + dailyTotal);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
}

WeeklyReport weeklyReport = new WeeklyReport(.....,dailyIncomes, dailyExpenses,....);

//to load next cards
        weekCount++;
        if (this.week == 1) {
            yearCount++;
            this.year = this.year - yearCount;
        }
        this.week = LocalDate.now()
                .minusYears(yearCount)
                .minusWeeks(weekCount)
                .get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
        weeklyReportList.add(weeklyReport);
        adapter.submitList(weeklyReportList);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(adapter.getItemCount() + 1);
```

How I set data to the chart:

```java
List<BarEntry> dailyDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            dailyDetails.add(new BarEntry(
                    (float) i, new float[]{
                    Float.parseFloat(weeklyReport.getDailyIncomes().get(i)),
                    Float.parseFloat(weeklyReport.getDailyExpenses().get(i))
            }));
        BarDataSet dailyDetailsSet = new BarDataSet(dailyDetails, "");
        String[] labels = {context.getString(R.string.incomes), context.getString(R.string.expenses)};
        //add x axis labels (days of week)
        WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
        int firstDay = weekFields.getFirstDayOfWeek().getValue();
        Log.i(TAG, "first day: " + firstDay);
        final List<String> xLabels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
            xLabels.add("DAY");
        if (firstDay == 7) {
            xLabels.add(0, LocalDate.now().with(DayOfWeek.of(7)).getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault()));
            for (int z = 1; z < 7; z++)
                xLabels.add(z, LocalDate.now().with(DayOfWeek.of(z)).getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault()));
        } else
            for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
                xLabels.add(LocalDate.now().with(DayOfWeek.of(y + 1)).getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault()));
dailyDetailsSet.setStackLabels(labels);
        BarData data = new BarData(dailyDetailsSet);
        chartView.setData(data);
        chartView.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                return xLabels.get((int) value);
            }
        });
        chartView.invalidate();
```

The chart looks like this:
[image: The chart looks like this]

I already tried using switch statements instead of loops but no luck. I'm sure that the data is accurate because there are some other charts like budget and monthly reports and nothing's wrong with them. It must be some silly mistake and I've been trying to fix this for three days but there's always something wrong.

Could someone help me and point out what I'm doing wrong? I'd appreciate it so much. Thanks. (Sorry if there's bad English)

Please ask me if you need to see more of the code.